# Grafting WSGI app on CherryPy via configuration file

Tags: wsgi, cherrypy

I have a WSGI app embedded (grafted) in my CherryPy server.

```
from my_app import application
import cherrypy

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cherrypy.config.update("server.conf")
    cherrypy.tree.graft(application, "/good_stuff/")

    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Where `server.conf` is the static configuration file which defines the server properties and so on.

```
[global]                                                  
server.socket_host = "0.0.0.0"
server.socket_port = 8087
server.thread_pool = 30
```

Now I would like to run CherryPy as a daemon service my using the **`cherryd`** utility, so I should turn the grafting part in the code to static configuration.

```
[global]
...
tree.graft = {my_app.application:"/good_stuff/"}
```

I couldn't find working examples on this, but it is clearly not OK:

```
AttributeError: 'ReloaderApp' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

as I try to launch it:

```
$ cherryd -c server.conf -i my_app
```

---

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
    [global]
    ...
--- tree.graft = {my_app.application:"/good_stuff"}
+++ tree.graft = {"/good_stuff":my_app.application}
```

In any case, I guessed it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5982638/1329340) question. I am not sure there is some point in the CherryPy docs where I could *see* this.

---

After reading Bernd Haug's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16709284/1329340), I realized that the `tree.graft(value)` translates to `cherrypy._cpconfig._tree_config_handler("graft", value)`, being the first "graft" just an arbitrary label. I could call `tree.foo` and still under the hood (if Bern Haug is right), I am actually `cherrypy.tree.graft`-ing the WSGI app.